# Opening and closing Iceweasel for Kiosk

Tags: raspberry-pi, kiosk, iceweasel

I'm trying to set a kiosk up that turns the HDMI port off at night and on weekends. I set up a crontab to turn it off but when it turns on the screen is black until some movement makes it load back. Becuase of this I am trying to make Iceweasel close and reopen fullscreen to load the screen. So far Iceweasel closes and the HDMI port turns off and on but I can't get Iceweasel to reopon. How can I do it?

Terminal

---

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ crontab -e

#HDMI O/F
18 * * * tvservice -o > /dev/null && pkill iceweasel
8 * * 1-5 tvservice -p > /dev/null && fbset -depth 8 && fbset -depth 16 && $
2 8 * * 1-5 /home/pi/run_iceweasel.sh
```

run_iceweasel.sh

---

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/iceweasel
end 0
```

Comment: What happens when you run `run_iceweasel.sh`?

Comment: If I click on it and open it in terminal iceweasel opens just fine

Comment: Click on it? As in the script? Also, did you read the cron job's log? That will probably shed some light on what happens when it tries to run your script.